# Solutions of $\tan(2x+3) = -1/2$

Tags: trigonometry

this is a silly question but here I go.

I was solving a question that required evaluating the derivative of an equation, which would result in finding a local min and a local max. The two points are in Quadrant 2 and 3,respectively.

The original equation is $\frac{\cos(2x+3)}{2e^x}$.

It came down to **$\tan(2x+3) = -1/2$**. After this, **$\arctan(-1/2) = -0.463647..$**. This lies in Q4, but I was wondering if I could use its complimentary angle (i.e., $2π - 0.463657$). The answer would be same, since **$\tan(2π - \theta) = - \tan(\theta)$**.

However, both yields different $x$ values and thus different answers.

I would be appreciated if you could explain the problem in my reasoning to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Here is the correct solution:

   $$\tan(2x+3) = -1/2\\ \iff
   2x-3=n\pi+\arctan\left(-\frac12\right)\:\:\text{for some }
   n\in\mathbb Z\\ \iff x=\frac{n\pi-3-\arctan\frac12}2\:\:\text{for
   some } n\in\mathbb Z$$

   > finding a local min and a local max. The two required points are in Quadrant 2 and 3, respectively.

   Since the original function is differentiable on $\mathbb R,$
   the required points are necessarily some of the above stationary
   points. And since $\tan$ is monotonic around its roots,
   the above stationary points alternate between minimum and maximum
   points.

   Plugging in $n=-1$ and $n=0$ gives $x=-3.30$ and $x=-1.73,$
   [which](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rtodtzolnp)
   are a quadrant-2 minimum and a quadrant-3 maximum,
   respectively.

   Hence, the complete solution set is
   $$\left\{\frac{n\pi-3-\arctan\frac12}2\,\Bigg\vert\,n\equiv-1,0\pmod4\right\}.$$
2. > It came down to **$\tan(2x+3) = -1/2$**. After this, **$\arctan(-1/2) = -0.463647..$**. This lies in Q4,

   Yes, by definition and convention,
   [$\arctanα$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rtodtzolnp) lies in
   the interval $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right),$ thus
   $$\tan\alpha=p\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies\alpha=\arctan p;$$ for
   example, try $\alpha=\pi$ which is in neither quadrant $4$ nor $1.$

   > but I was wondering if I could use its complimentary angle (i.e., $2π - 0.463657$). The answer would be same, since **$\tan(2π -
   > \theta) = - \tan(\theta)$**.

   The complementary angle of $θ$ is $\displaystyle\left(\frac\pi2-θ\right)$ rather
   than $\left(2\pi+θ\right).$

   And yes,
   $$\tan\alpha=p\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies\alpha=2\pi+\arctan p,$$
   as you've just illustrated.

   > However, both yields different $x$ values and thus different answers.

   Yes, your two suggested answers correspond to $n=0$ and $n=2,$ which give the [points](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rtodtzolnp) $x=-1.73$ and  $x=1.41,$ respectively. Only the former (out of infinitely many points) satisfies this exercise's requirement.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. You plugged in 'n = -1 and n = 0' to arrive at the correct answers. But, how can one determine which 'n' to plug in to attain correct answers?

Comment: @Gtexx Thanks for the observation; I've edited the answer. P.S. Do click on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Note the tangent function has a period of $\pi$. Hence,

$$\begin{align}\tan(2x+3)&=-1/2\\
\implies 2x+3&=\arctan(-1/2)+n\pi,\quad n\in\mathbb Z\\
&\approx -0.46365+n\pi,\quad n\in\mathbb Z\\
\implies x&\approx -1.73+n\frac{\pi}{2},\quad n\in\mathbb Z\end{align}.$$

Note $x$ is in quadrant I,II,III, IV when
$n\equiv 2,3,0,1 \quad (\mod 4), $ respectively.